# Swift weak variable behaviour difference?

Tags: swift, weak-references, sknode

I came across some old Swift code (badly written from when I was first playing with the language back in June) and I was curious why the function `test` fails, but `test2` works?

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Its a silly example as self.node would need adding to the scene. I was just curios as to why they behave differently, my guess is its maybe the way each is implemented or the way the complier handles each knowing there correct use.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    weak var node: SKNode!
    weak var color: SKColor!

    func test() {
        self.node = SKNode()
        print(self.node) // Why nil here?
    }

    func test2() {
        self.color = SKColor()
        print(self.color) // Works fine ...
    }
}
```

I understand the objects are created in the scope of the function and assigned to a variable declared as weak, its more about why the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, the value of a weak variable will only be determined at run-time. You can read more about this at: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48

Comment: Much appreciated, I will check that out. Thank you Sir

Comment: Can you paste the paragraph/explanation you refer to, the only thing I can find in the linked doc is "Weak references must be declared as variables, to indicate that their value can change at runtime. A weak reference cannot be declared as a constant."